# Setting minimum and maximum of scale_size for geom_tex and geom_point independently

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to set a maximum and minimum in scale_size for geom_text and geom_point independently?
For instance, in this plot, I would like make the size of the points or circles range larger than the text (otherwise, the text masks the circles).

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=mpg, x=cyl,size=cyl)) + 
  geom_point(shape=21) +
  geom_text(aes(label=rownames(mtcars),size=hp)) +
  scale_size(range = c(2, 10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may adjust the text size in `geom_text` and the general aesthetics (or in `geom_point`):

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=mpg, x=cyl,size=15*cyl)) + 
    geom_point(shape=21) +
    geom_text(aes(label=rownames(mtcars),size=10*hp/max(hp))) +
    scale_size(range = c(2, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, one thing though! Do you know how to remove the "a" text from the legend?

Comment: @Adel Yes, you only have to add `show.legend = FALSE` inside `geom_text`: `geom_text(aes(label=rownames(mtcars),size=10*hp/max(hp)), show.legend = FALSE) `

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I had a problem, but now working. Just ignore my edited message.